# How do you hide sensitive configuration data from the Apache Flink configuration dashboard?

Tags: java, apache-flink

We're starting to use Apache Flink for data streaming. It's processing data and then updating the database in the sinks. We configure the database endpoints/credentials as Flink Configuration data (as we have the standard dev/test/prod setup), but unfortunately the passwords/api-keys are showing in plaintext in the Flink Configuration dashboard, along with all the other configuration data.

Is there a way of configuring flink so that the java code can still access the sensitive password information via [ParameterTool](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/utils/ParameterTool.html) (or similar) but the sensitive data is *not* displayed in the Flink Dashboard?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the cluster level configuration (`flink-conf.yaml`) this feature is supported. What one needs to do in order to not display secret values is to include `secret` or `password` in the key (e.g. the values of `cluster.password` or `secret.plan` won't be displayed).

However, this feature is not yet supported for the user configuration as you would need it when using the `ParameterTool` and passing global job parameters via `ExecutionConfig.setGlobalJobParameters`. I've filed [FLINK-14047](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-14047) in order to add this feature to Flink.

## Update

[FLINK-14047](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-14047) has been merged into Flink 1.10. Now also sensitive user configuration values will be filtered out if their key names contain either `password` or `secret`.

Comment: Aaah, that's a shame. It's the user-config that we are using. We've changed our code to create a copy of `ParameterTool` with the secrets redacted before passing to `ExecutionConfig.setGlobalJobParameter` until https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-14047 is fixed

Comment: Quick update, I've opened a PR for FLINK-14047: https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/9672. I hope that we can review and merge it soon.

Comment: @agentgonzo FLINK-14047 has been merged into Flink 1.10. You can try it out with the latest snapshot version.

Comment: We're deploying on AWS, so will need to wait until it gets adopted by them... but I'll see if I can get a local cluster running when I get some time (hopefully next week)

Comment: Let me know if there are any other problems you might encounter.